# A Question Regarding Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

For question 7, I have figured out the angles for 2 triangles, the one with RJh and the one with PJh. I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Jesus man. Can you type up the question or at least post a better picture? I didn't know potatoes were still around.

Comment: The picture is all that matters. Just find h

Comment: Posting a better picture is probably impossible.  The down-votes here don't make sense.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The picture he posted previously (when the down votes began) didn't even include this picture. It was really blurry and of the entire page (not just the specific problem).

Comment: Has anyone up-voted the question besides me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so look at my outline:

http://sketchtoy.com/60466249

We've got:

$$100^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$h=x\tan 18$$
$$h=y \tan 20$$

Right off the bat, we can substitute the $h$'s:

$$x\tan 18=y \tan 20$$

Welp, let's just solve for one variable. Let's just use $y$ (doesn't matter):

$$y=\frac{x \tan 18}{\tan 20}$$

Plug it in:

$$100^2=x^2+\left(\frac{x \tan 18}{\tan 20}\right)^2$$

Simplify:

$$10000=x^2\left(1+\left(\frac{\tan 18}{\tan 20}\right)^2\right)$$

Very easy to get $x$ now:

$$x \approx 74.5992 \text { m}$$

From $x$, we'll get $h$ to be:

$$h=x \tan 18 \approx 24.2388 \text{ m}$$

If you find $y$ and then find $h$ from there, you'll get the same answer.

Comment: Have you up-voted the question, or am I the only one so far?